# Is there any alternative for commands in Magento?

Tags: magento2, command-line

We are all known that there are commands we need to run at some instances in Magento.Is there any possibilities to make things work without running commands?

For example, we can flush the `cache`even in admin panel of `Magento`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it but you should avoid doing manual. But still here are some alternative you can do.

```
Command : bin/magento setup:upgrade
Alternative : Update app/etc/config.php to add newly created module entry.

Command : bin/magento setup:di:compile
Alternative : Delete generated/* content.

Command : bin/magento cache:clean
Alternative : Delete var/cache/* content
```

These are few alternatives. But still better to run the commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf var/generation/* &&
rm -rf var/cache/* &&
rm -rf var/page_cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension which will let you reindex your site from admin

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-reindex

Normally that's command line only